# ERROR: Split metadata size exceeded 10000000

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I'm getting the error `The job initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Split metadata size exceeded 10000000.` when I try to run a job on hadoop.

Internet search was indicated for the service of changing a `mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize` option to -1 in the `mapred-site.xml` file. But you can't edit this option via file in the Google cluster.

I also tried setting an option via the command line using `-Dmapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize = -1`, but to no avail.

I tried to put an option inside the source code using:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration ();
Config.set ("mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize", "-1");
```

But it's still making the same mistake. Alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Two comments:

I'm not sure if the `-Dmapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize = -1` would work *without* spaces, but I don't think the spaces are allowed.

Secondly, it looks like you're setting it in a configuration that your job isn't using. Try using the configuration that your job is using --

```
job.getConfiguration.set("mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize", "-1");
```

That just worked for me. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

When setting config options, it is important that you implement Tool interface and that you set those options in the run method. Check this to get an example.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33365552/3998212