# Error when execute Map-Reduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I use **hadoop3.1.0** to run Mapreduce WordCount program on Ubuntu,but it always got this INFO.

I saw someone ask this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333080/getting-the-tool-interface-warning-even-though-it-is-implemented) before,but that can't work.

I want to know which file should i modify,or something that i miss.

My java program is from [here](https://www.guru99.com/create-your-first-hadoop-program.html).

`master@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MapReduceTutorial$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar ProductSalePerCountry.jar /inputMapReduce /mapreduce_output_sales`

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar ProductSalePerCountry.jar /inputMapReduce /mapreduce_output_sales
2018-05-20 00:58:37,856 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at kevin-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1:8032
2018-05-20 00:58:38,511 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at kevin-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1:8032
2018-05-20 00:58:38,980 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2018-05-20 00:58:39,058 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/master/.staging/job_1526748071526_0004
2018-05-20 00:58:39,579 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2018-05-20 00:58:39,773 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
2018-05-20 00:58:39,926 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-05-20 00:58:40,251 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1526748071526_0004
2018-05-20 00:58:40,254 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2018-05-20 00:58:40,742 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-05-20 00:58:40,744 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-05-20 00:58:40,930 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1526748071526_0004
2018-05-20 00:58:41,095 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://kevin-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1526748071526_0004/
2018-05-20 00:58:41,097 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1526748071526_0004
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
<description>Parent directory for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS </name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system. </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>/home/master/hdfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/home/master/hdfs/data</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.permissions</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
   <configuration>
        <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
         <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
         </property>
        <property>
         <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
         <value>kevin-VirtualBox</value>
          </property>
    </configuration>
```

**mapred-site.sml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
<property>  
 <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>  
</configuration>
```

**jps**

```
4948 Jps
2856 NodeManager
2088 NameNode
2731 ResourceManager
2207 DataNode
```

**My URL to track the job**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you've pasted your question twice? Also, the logs you've posted don't contain any useful information - you should follow the tracking URL it gives and try and find the real error.

Comment: sorry,I already edited it.

Comment: Did you find the real error by following the tracking URL?

Comment: 15/02/04 16:35:25 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.

Comment: I still got this error like URL i posted.

Comment: I thinks this is key error

Comment: `2018-05-20 00:58:41,095 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://kevin-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1526748071526_0004/
` is where you will find the error.

Comment: oh.I know what u mean.I will post this later

Comment: @BenWatson sorry for later post my URL,I post in my article.

Comment: Based on that image, YARN has no memory available to run an application in a NodeManager. Can you also show the `ApplicationMaster` page from that one?

Comment: Also, how much memory did you give to VirtualBox? Anything less than 6GB probably won't run smoothly with the default Hadoop properties.

Comment: I give my V-box 10GB.

Comment: @cricket_007 I post in my article,is that u want?

Comment: On the second image, in the top row. Two apps are waiting to be ran. However, 0 total memory is available and 0 vCores are available. Therefore, your executions are stuck waiting for NodeManager resources to register with the ResourceManager. I would go find the logs for each process, and even do a start/stop of the YARN processes to see if those values start changing

Comment: Unrelated to that, though, I would suggest setting `fs.defaultFS` to be `hdfs://kevin-VirtualBox:54310`

Comment: so how do i give memory to my hdfs or Vcores. sorry i am beginner for hadoop

Comment: any setup do i miss?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for help. I change YARN memory.it's work

Comment: Sorry missed your comments. Feel free to answer your own question below with the properties you added rather than just leave a comment

Comment: @cricket_007 you can answer below I will accept it

Comment: I'm not sure which settings you gave to change the YARN memory.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok i post answer below,finally thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @cricket_007
My problem is i don't give memmory to **YARN**

sets the maximum memory YARN can utilize In yarn-site.xml

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>40960</value>
```

specifying the minimum unit of RAM to allocate

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>2048</value>
```